# android saveinstance saving vector datatypes

Tags: android, vector, orientation, savestate

I am making an application which is currently working perfectly but with only 1 problem...
As we all know that the activity is destroyed and recreated when user changes the orientation of the phone... my activity needs to save a vector full of objects wen the activity is recreated... i checked the OnSaveInstance() method and found that there is no way a vector can be stored... Does any1 have a suggestion for storing vector so that i can retrieve it on recreation of Activity???

Any help will be appreciated...

Thanx...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, there's a mechanism in place for this purpose.

1. Implement/override [`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()) in your `Activity` class, returning the state object you want to persist across orientation changes (in this case, a vector or what not)
2. In your `onCreate` or `onStart` or what not, access the stored object by calling [`getLastNonConfigurationInstance`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLastNonConfigurationInstance()). If it's null, recreate the object.

Comment: WOW!! Thanx Roman Nurik... it worked like a charm... though my my problems solved but can we store more than 1 object like the way u explained... coz it returns only the last copnfiguration... so i guess it stores only 1 object... correct me if i'm wrong... thanx again...